# Swift protocol and a method returning "some View"

Tags: swift, swiftui

So a protocol doesn't support `some View` as a return type... I'm trying this:

```
public extension View {
    func popSheet(isPresented: Binding<Bool>, arrowEdge: Edge = .bottom, content: @escaping () -> PopSheet) -> some View {
        Group {
            if UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .pad {
                popover(isPresented: isPresented, attachmentAnchor: .rect(.bounds), arrowEdge: arrowEdge, content: {
                    content().popover()
                })
            } else {
                actionSheet(isPresented: isPresented, content: {
                    content().actionSheet()
                })
            }
        }
    }
}

protocol PopSheet {
    func actionSheet() -> ActionSheet
    associatedtype View
    func popover() -> View
}
```

But the whole function declaration fails and the  `content().popover()` errors as well.

`Method must be declared internal because its parameter uses an internal type`

`Protocol 'PopSheet' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements`

`Member 'popover' cannot be used on value of protocol type 'PopSheet'; use a generic constraint instead`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's nothing fundamentally wrong here. Just several small mistakes.

First, your `View` associatedtype has nothing to do with `SwiftUI.View`. It just happens to have the same name. What you likely meant was this:

```
public protocol PopSheet {
    associatedtype V: View   // Create a new type that conforms to View
    func actionSheet() -> ActionSheet
    func popover() -> V
}
```

Your second problem is that you can't rely on PopSheet directly, since it has an associatedtype. You mean that you expect some *concrete* type that conforms to PopSheet:

```
func popSheet<Sheet: PopSheet>(isPresented: Binding<Bool>, 
                               arrowEdge: Edge = .bottom, 
                               content: @escaping () -> Sheet) -> some View {
```

With that, your implementation should be fine.

Comment: This fixed error 2 & 3, but I still get a similar error to the 1st `Instance method must be declared internal because its generic parameter uses an internal type`.

Comment: That's because the extension is marked `public`, but the PopSheet. In my answer, I added `public` to PopSheet.

Answer (score 0):

For the `use a generic constraint instead` issue, the reason is:

> ...
>
> That’s something that happens when we try to reference a generic protocol directly — that is, a protocol that has either associated types, or requires the conforming type (which `Self` refers to) to be known. For example, the built-in `Equatable` protocol uses `Self` within its declaration
>
> ...

You can find detailed explanation in this [great blog post](https://www.swiftbysundell.com/questions/referencing-generic-protocols/).

Great day, and Happy coding!